# Iteration through array and objects with properties

Tags: javascript, raphael, qtip2

I`m not sure if the title of question is correct. Look at the code:

```
var trails = new Array(trail1, trail2, trail3, trail4, trail5, trail6, trail7, trail8, trail9, trail10, trail11, trail12, trail13);
    var circles = new Array(circle1, circle2, circle3, circle4, circle5, circle6, circle7, circle8, circle9, circle10, circle11, circle12, circle13);
    var texts = new Array(text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, text7, text8, text9, text10, text11, text12, text13);
    for(var i=0;i<=13;i++) {
        $([trails[i].node,circles[i].node,texts[i].node]).qtip({
        content: {
            text: 'test qtip',
            title: {text: 'test', button: 'close'}
        },
        position: {
            target: 'mouse',
            adjust: {mouse: false}
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click'
        },
        style: 'qtip-rounded qtip-shadow qtip-blue',
        hide: {
            event: 'click '
        }
    });
    }
```

In this example I`m calling an array elements inside another array, so i'm not sure it's correct, but otherwise .qtip will not show when click on circle[i] or text[i], but only when onclick the trails[i]. There is also a .node property which make this issue much more complicated for beginner. Have any ideas how to improve the code to make it work?

Comment: What exactly are all these trails, circles and texts?

Comment: trails, circles and texts are SVGs generated by RaphaelJS

Comment: a jsfiddle would help...

Comment: code consist of 700 lines, but i`ll try to modify it

Answer (score 0):

First: Your loop has '<=' where your arrays contain 13 items, the '<=' will iterate 14 times probably causing whatever error your experiencing...

Just to clean up the code a bit...(this part is arbitrary)

```
var trails = [],circles = [],texts = [], i = 13;
while (i--){
    trails[i] = eval('trail'+i);//parses the text to return your js variable
    circles[i] = eval('circle'+i);
    texts[i] = eval('text'+i);
    . . .
    /** Continue with whatever else you wish to do inside the loop,
     *  I just included this bit to show how you can instantiate your
     *  arrays without having to hard code each of your variables...
     *  Also, it is possible to use the variables name as a reference
     *  inside the array like so: trails['trail'+i] = . . . 
     *  that way you can still call each variable by name. 
     */
}
```

And just as a tip, js gets cranky when using the keywork 'new' for arrays, use '[]' instead, you can read why here: [W3Schools.com - JS - Best Practices](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_best_practices.asp)